# My application quits after adding AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

I added

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

I then add this in my MainActivity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Then I changed Extends **Acitivity** to **AppCompatActivity**

And my application crashes at startup I have no errors I looked in the logs

Answer (score 1):

Did you check parent theme of `AppTheme` in `styles.xml`?

parent theme should inherit `Theme.AppCompat.*`